# Running py.test tests from another pip-installed package against local code

Tags: python, pytest

I am building a package that provides (1) a fixed interface with (2) pluggable drivers. The desired driver will be selectable by the user of the package. My package will include at least one driver with it, but I would like other developers to be able to implement and validate drivers that conform to the package's interface. As such, **I would like these developers to be able to run *my* tests against *their* drivers.**

Currently, I am using py.test's parametrized fixtures to inject my driver(s) into my tests:

```py
# conftest.py
import my_pkg
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[my_pkg.MyDriver])
def driver(request):
    return request.param
```

```py
# my_pkg/tests/conftest.py
import my_pkg
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_interface(driver):
    return my_pkg.MyInterface(driver)
```

```py
# my_pkg/tests/test_my_interface.py
def test_that_it_does_the_right_thing(my_interface):
    assert my_interface.some_method() == "some return value"
```

I structured it this way in the hopes that someone would be able to collect and run my tests against their version of the `driver` fixture. In other words, *their* package would look something like this:

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=["my-pkg"])
```

```py
# conftest.py
import their_pkg
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[their_pkg.TheirDriver])
def driver(request):
    return request.param
```

Obviously this is not enough to get it to work, because py.test doesn't appear to offer an option to inject tests from external packages. **But how, if at all, is this possible?**

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030987/running-pytest-tests-in-another-python-package) seems to be conceptually similar, but the author appears to be working entirely within one codebase. I would like a *completely separate* pip-installed package to be able to reference tests included in *my* pip-installed package.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I solved this](https://github.com/elliterate/capybara.py/commit/fb60490326dec14d76a4567eebc6661fa7bf9dac) by:

1. implementing [a custom py.test collector](https://github.com/elliterate/capybara.py/commit/fb60490326dec14d76a4567eebc6661fa7bf9dac#diff-0791e3224f561b8afce0679fd5d66982) that grafts the necessary suite of tests from my package,
2. requiring the consumer to instantiate a custom class of mine, `my_pkg.MyDriverSuite`, in one of their test files, then,
3. writing [a custom py.test plugin](https://github.com/elliterate/capybara.py/commit/fb60490326dec14d76a4567eebc6661fa7bf9dac#diff-5c50b891fe3e45b64e30a78fff8f42d1) that uses the `pytest_pycollect_makeitem` hook to intercept the custom instance and inject my collector.

(Note: This approach obviated the use of parametrized fixtures.)

---

The custom collector was by far the trickiest part to figure out, as it required lots of digging through the py.test internals and, ultimately, re-implementing a stripped-down version of a core py.test collector, `Session`, with a custom session `Config` whose `rootdir` was set to that of my package.

Comment: Hi @ian-lesperance, looking back at this after a few years, are you still happy with your solution and are you aware of any other solutions that perhaps require less changes?

Comment: An alternative solution may be described here: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/421#issuecomment-943386533